# NVD3 pie chart explode feature

Tags: nvd3.js

I am trying to replace my Kendo charts with NVD3 charts. In NVD3 pie chart, I did not see explode option on slice click. Is there easy way to achieve it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I able to explode slice of pie chart using below function. I got the help from http://jsfiddle.net/zephod/L4pyk79e/2/

I added below function in nv.d3.js

```
            var explode = function (x, index) {
                var offset = 10;
                var angle = (x.startAngle + x.endAngle) / 2;
                var xOff = Math.sin(angle) * offset;
                var yOff = -Math.cos(angle) * offset;
                return "translate(" + xOff + "," + yOff + ")";
            }
```

Calling it as below from ae.on('click', function (d, i).

d3.select(this).select("path").transition()
                            .duration(70)
                            .attr("transform", explode);

to undo, call same function with offset=0

Answer (score 0):

nvd3 does not currently support exploding the pie chart.  it's community driven though, so you can send them a pull request if you add the feature!  You'll want to modify the pie.js and pieChart.js model files.